# Adding WindowsImageBackup to protected folders in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, backup, protected

I use the Windows 10 backup program to save a full system image to a secondary harddisk (D:). To prevent ransomware from accessing it I am considering adding  D:\WindowsImageBackup to "Protected folders" in "Windows Defender Security Center". Can this interfere with a restore operation?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question?  Are you asking if you protect the folder that contains your Windows images from being modified if you will still be able to restore the images, contained within the directory?  You should edit your question to clarify your question.